Firebase App Check: How can I get status in my Android app?
Is there some approach to get App-check status: can the app use Firebase services or not? For instance if debug token or app SHA-256 doesn't added into Firebase console. In this case I want to show some notification in the app to inform users about the issue. Now I'm using only RTDB, but other Firebase services possibly will connected later.
Currently I getting the following error trying call RTDB, when I still do not add debug token in Firebase App-check console:
   java.lang.Exception: Client is offline
    at com.google.firebase.database.connection.PersistentConnectionImpl.lambda$get$1$com-google-firebase-database-connection-PersistentConnectionImpl(PersistentConnectionImpl.java:441)
    at com.google.firebase.database.connection.PersistentConnectionImpl$$ExternalSyntheticLambda2.run(Unknown Source:8)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

